# How to Optimize COUNT() when using in Large Loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-optimization

I have a situation where I am showing the categories and along with it the number of products in those and all internal sub and subcategories (3 level only)

Here is my SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count_brand_prod FROM `shop_products` 
WHERE (`shop_products`.`category_id` IN (28,59,29,60,30,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,27)
OR `shop_products`.`parent_category_id` = '27') 
AND `brand_id` = '88' 
AND `pharmacy_id` = '10';
```

I am looping it on Parent Categories and Sub categories, also using the above query for each category to count number of product exist in category and any level of that category. For a reason I am using IN operator which contains all the ID's of categories/ subcategories and sub-sub level.

While looping it is slowing down the page access. Can anyone help how can i optimize the query to load my page faster?

Comment: do you need the count immediately (i.e. before the next loop runs)?

Comment: I need it with every iteration. As every iteration it prints the sub-category name and I want to ensure if there are any single item/ product for the parent and subsequent categories + brand_id I will show the category otherwise will skip it.

Comment: While looping... what is changing? Only the parent_category_id?

Comment: parent_category_id and shop_products.category_id as category_id will contains all the categories and sub cat and sub sub cat Id's

Comment: @twister787 create view

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the IDs columns are indexed, ie. has a key.
If not add missing indexes, for example using this alter table query:

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_products`
ADD INDEX `id` (`id`),
ADD INDEX `category_id` (`category_id`),
ADD INDEX `parent_category_id` (`parent_category_id`),
ADD INDEX `brand_id` (`brand_id`),
ADD INDEX `pharmacy_id` (`pharmacy_id`)
;
```

Note: remove lines with already existing indexes first!

Comment: I have all those fields already indexed! but still the issue is there!

Comment: A composite `INDEX(brand_id, pharmacy_id)` will be better than individual indexes.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slowness you can use join or subquery.

```
(shop_products.category_id IN (28,59,29,60,30,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,27)
```

In another table, a parent id for these categories id should be available to use join.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only changing the `parent_category_id` in your query while looping it, then count everything grouped by the `parent_category_id`:

```
SELECT `parent_category_id`, COUNT(id) as count_brand_prod FROM `shop_products` 
WHERE `category_id` IN (28,59,29,60,30,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,27)
AND `brand_id` = '88' 
AND `pharmacy_id` = '10'
GROUP BY `parent_category_id`;
```

So you will have just one query and the rest of calculation will be processed in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A composite `INDEX(brand_id, pharmacy_id)` will be better than individual indexes.  It will help the query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following composite and covering index:

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_products` ADD INDEX `shop_products_idx_id_id_id` (`brand_id`, `pharmacy_id`, `id`);
```

Also, remove the single quotes around the numeric fields, which may cause unrequired cast, which might prevent index use.

So the query you should run after indexing is:

```
SELECT
        COUNT(`shop_products`.id) AS count_brand_prod 
    FROM
        `shop_products` 
    WHERE
        (
            `shop_products`.`category_id` IN (
                28, 59, 29, 60, 30, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 27
            ) 
            OR `shop_products`.`parent_category_id` = 27
        ) 
        AND `shop_products`.`brand_id` = 88
        AND `shop_products`.`pharmacy_id` = 10
```